# Can I use .gitignore with TFVC?

Tags: gitignore, tfvc

I started using TFVC recently. I was wondering if I can use .gitignore file with TFVC? I am keeping asp.net code in the repository and don't want build related files and folders to get checked in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, in my experience you can use .gitignore file in TFVC. It should work the same. If you want information about how to get the .gitignore file, you can refer the following link -

https://cache404.net/2020/06/04/getting-and-using-gitignore/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using local workspaces you can use a .tfignore that follows the same format as .gitignore.

[Follow this for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155786.aspx)

Note: The exact use case is not supported by TFVC.